# Why can't C# infer the type of anonymous delegates/functions in some cases?

Tags: c#, delegates, type-inference, implicit-conversion, anonymous-function

I'm using C# 12.

When assigning a function to an implicitly-typed (var) variable, C# can infer the type successfully, such as in this example:

```
// Scenario A
var func = () => "Hello World"; // no problem here, infers the type Func<string>
```

However, C# cannot infer the type when the function is used in a switch:

```
// Scenario B
// the type cannot be inferred, you must replace "var" with "Func<string>"
var func = true switch
{
    false => () => "Hello World",
    true => () => "Foo Bar"
};
```

Furthermore, you cannot instantly invoke a function unless you explicitly cast it to `Func<string>` first:

```
// Scenario C
var str = (() => "Hello World")(); // does not work

// Scenario D
var str = ((Func<string>)(() => "Hello World"))(); // works
```

Is there a technical reason why the type `Func<string>` cannot be inferred in all scenarios? I don't see why it couldn't, since **Scenario A** proves that it is possible to infer `Func<string>`. Is this a C# bug?

[image]

Comment: Looking at the [proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/lambda-improvements#natural-function-type) that enabled you to do `var func = () => "Hello World";`, it doesn't really add much regarding type inference. All it says is that lambdas now have a natural delegate type, and this type will be used when you initialise a `var` with a lambda. This natural delegate type isn't really used anywhere else.

Comment: So basically, `var func = () => "Hello World";` is the only case where C# can find a "proper" type for a lambda without any additional information. In all other situations, it needs a delegate/expression tree type *somewhere*. So the answer to your question is basically, it doesn't work because this is not implemented. If you are not satisfied with that, please edit to [clarify what kind of answer you are looking for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293815/5133585).

Comment: @Sweeper thank you for finding that info. I'm just looking for whether it is even possible for the type to be inferred, and if the C# guys just didn't finish implementing it. Based on your information, it sounds like it's an incomplete implementation.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is technically not "type inference" according to the C# spec. "Type inference" is the inference of type parameters when you call a method. Other processes may *involve* type inference, such as finding the best common type, but they are not literally called "type inference". In any case, there are no plans to implement this as far as I know. I'd imagine implementing this in a consistent way would be rather tricky though.

Comment: Not incomplete its is working just not with the QoL Features you would like to have. Features have a cost and a value beyond you personal needs. So either it never became relevant enough to be implemented or others where more relevant or no one thought about it or missed it till now. For example i never missed it.

Comment: @Sweeper arguably this should work for `switch` expressions (B). The [`switch` expressions feature spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#switch-expression) states _"The type of the switch_expression is the best common type (§11.6.3.15) of the expressions appearing to the right of the => tokens of the switch_expression_arms if such a type exists and the expression in every arm of the switch expression can be implicitly converted to that type."_. And natural function types should work there.

Comment: As the corresponding feature doc states -  _"Function_types are used in a few specific contexts only: .... - method type inference (§11.6.3) and best common type (§11.6.3.15)"_

Comment: @user3163495 Also see the [Directly invoked anonymous functions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4748) proposal.

Comment: @GuruStron That's just the changes in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/lambda-improvements#type-inference), and I don't see anything in there that could help. Sure, they take function types into account to an extent, but following the whole type inference process, there still needs to be a proper delegate type *somewhere*, for this to work.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes. It  shows an example - `var fs = new[] { (string s) => s.Length, (string s) => int.Parse(s) };` which now works. Arguably it should work for the `switch` expression case (i.e. it is able to determine best common type for array, and `switch` expression is referring to the same process as far as I understand). Though I'm not fluent enough with spec to be able to argue.

Comment: Created an [issue in the compiler repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/71649) addressing the `switch` expression case. Will see what more knowledgeable people than me will say.

Comment: @GuruStron what are your opinions on Scenario C? the JavaScript-like IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Shouldn't the type be inferred there also?

Comment: @Sweeper what are your opinions on Scenario C? the JavaScript-like IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Shouldn't the type be inferred there also?

Comment: @user3163495 see the "Directly invoked anonymous functions" proposal I've linked earlier.